# Actionscript (Flex) streamed upload to Django

Tags: django, apache-flex

I want to upload large image files from actionscript from Flex. The file upload tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/ handles streamed file upload from a form so the file is transformed in request.FILE['name'], but I don't know how to replicate this in actionscript. I tried also to transfer the file as POST argument, but I get error:

```
in handle_uploaded_file for chunk in f.chunks():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'chunks'
```

Is it error in my python code that I have to use only request.FILE or is it problem in my actionscript? What is the proper way to upload file without form. Here is my actionscript code:

```
var upload:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(UploadURL+"?var="+Math.random());
var sendVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
upload.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
upload.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, image.uploadedEvent);
sendVars.file = image.getBytearray(); // image is a JPEG encoded ByteArray
request.data = sendVars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.requestHeaders.push(header);
upload.load(request);
```

here is django part:

```
def upload_file(request): 
  if request.method == 'POST':
    handle_uploaded_file(request.POST.get('file'))
  return HttpResponse()

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
  destination = open('file.dat', 'wb+')
  for chunk in f.chunks():
      destination.write(chunk)
  destination.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do understand that streaming is not equal to HTTP upload right?  Have you even tried to debug at all?  I would imagine that your file `f` is the full file image and doesn't have chunks because it was never streamed in the first place.